# How long to wait before becoming successful freelancer as a mobile app developer

Tags: software-industry, resignation, software-development, freelancing

Usually how long does it take to become successful as freelance mobile developer I spent 6 months  time freelancing part  time but looks like I am reaching no where ,not sure should I continue freelance or take more responsibility at my current job

EDIT
I have 3 years experience,I have a job 40 hrs/week ,someday I want to quit and work for myself only but currently it seems too difficult

Comment: I have been able to get only one contract in past 6 months

Comment: I suggest the most common time to become a successful freelance mobile developer is infinite, as it is difficult to achieve without a good product idea that you can implement solely on your own.

Comment: @user8227740, It may take a few years. In the beginning, you may have to give estimated costs to the clients, which is lower than the actual costs due to the pricing pressure and competition. After a few years, as your software skills and your business management skills increase, you can start presenting good and accurate estimated costs to the clients, and start making nice profits. Good luck :-)

Comment: Can you share some context here? Are you fresh out of school? Are you currently freelancing as a secondary activity (that's what I understand when you talk about your "current job")? What was your goal launching your freelance activity?

Answer (score 3):

How successful you are at freelancing is more affected by your marketing acumen than it is by your experience developing software. And tbh a lot of software developers *don't* have great marketing acumen.

Having a good network of people that you can work with helps too. If you don't know a bunch of people who are always looking for devs and are willing to pay for them then your ability to make a freelancing is going to be limited.

Comment: There's a reason the western world functions on "it's not what you know it's who you know".

Answer (score -1):

"Freelancing" means that you undertake to be "an independent, self-sustaining businessman."  Especially given the dynamics of software development – which is, in my opinion, "necessarily a **team** effort," I think that you should instead bloom where you are planted.  You are already "part of a *team,"* and that **team** is far more likely to be successful than you would be on your own.